# How to backup/restore full-disk encryption?

Tags: backup, encryption, files, restore

How to backup/restore full-disk encryption ubuntu 11.10? I would like to put the RAW encrypted file system and restore on another computer.

Encryption Details:
crypt setup via Ubuntu alterate CD Installer
only thing unencrypted is /boot

File systems setup:
boot- j
swap-swap
everything else-ext 4

Any suggestions?
I have considered backing up the file system stripped of encryption, but I would prefer to keep the os encrypted while transferring.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have never done it myself but I imagine if you are wanted to make an exact copy of the encrypted disk then it would be easiest to back up the entire partition using **ddrescue**, **[clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/)** or something similar. Then restoring to a new HD.